# JQuery, sort array of tiles using data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Given a landing page of product slot tiles, my goal is to reorder these tiles based on a priority value.
I'm using the following call to return an array of tiles with sewing class and show class:

```
$(".show.sewing.tile-wrap").parent();
```

Now I would like to sort this returned array, ordered by the values found in each tile's data-prioritysort attribute.
Here is my typical HTML product slot tile:

```
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="11" >
  <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
     <div class="slug">
         <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
         <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
         <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
     </div>
    <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
    <div class="slot-cta">
        <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
        title="25% Off Description."
        alt="25% Off Description.">
        <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>
        <p><!-- Description.--></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit: To clarify the goal, this sort to be implemented once at document.ready. I've implemented the second solution found in the replies to my first post but for some reason the tiles without show class display and sort to top.

Comment: Do you simply want the array to be sorted, or do you want the DOM elements to be sorted too?  Is the following jsfiddle any use?  http://jsfiddle.net/ve7eg6pj/

Comment: DOM elements. Goal is for the tiles to display in the order of priority as set by the data attribute. The page has 96 tiles that wrap in 4-up rows. The display of filtered tiles is invoked by clicking the sewing category button. If an item sells out the show class is removed. To boost visibility of a poor performer the tile is given a lower number to move it towards upper left. This had been achieved in the past by production team editing semantic markup. I prefer to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: BTW, thank you for taking the time to set up the fiddle. It is somewhat helpful but I'm not yet able to solve this using your example.

Comment: You're welcome.  Not sure why you're not able to solve your problem, StackOverflow gets rather full of these kind of 'how-do-i-do-this-one-thing' type questions.  Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j248k6z9/ and also these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+sort+by+attribute

Comment: My difficulty is being under a tight deadline and not having enough understanding to quickly wrap my mind around the problem. I had been mulling over your previous example and some others and am beginning to grasp how to implement this into my page. Stack overflow is an amazing resource filled with generous people. Thank you most sincerely for sharing your time and knowledge.

Comment: So the problem is solved?

Comment: Actually not completely. When the show tags are removed from some tiles those sort to the top and are displayed. I'm thinking I would have to get only those children of the tileset with show tags. I thought I had done this with the initial jQuery call

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var elems = $(".show.sewing.tile-wrap").parent()
, t = 0
, data = $.map(elems, function (value, key) {
    var j = $(value).data("prioritysort");
    // `t` : greatest `data-prioritysort` value
    t = j > t ? j : t;
    return j
})
// create array having `length` 1 greater than `t`
, n = new Array(t + 1)
// return `html` of elements having `data-prioritysort` value
// from least to greatest
, ret = $.map(n, function (value, key) {
    // `d` : index of item within `data` at `key` less than `t`
    var d = $.inArray(key, data);
    // return `html` of item within `data` at `key` index
    return d !== -1 ? elems[d].outerHTML : null
});
// replace `elems` with `ret`
elems.replaceWith(function (i, el) {
    return ret[i]
});
```

```js
var elems = $(".show.sewing.tile-wrap").parent(),
    t = 0,
    data = $.map(elems, function (value, key) {
        var j = $(value).data("prioritysort");
        t = j > t ? j : t;
        return j
    }),
    n = new Array(t + 1),
    ret = $.map(n, function (value, key) {
        var d = $.inArray(key, data);
        return d !== -1 ? elems[d].outerHTML : null
    });
$("button").on("click", function () {
    elems.replaceWith(function (i, el) {
    return ret[i]
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="11">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->11</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="5">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="7">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->7</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="3">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="8">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->8</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="9">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->9</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="1">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="10">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->10</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="4">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="6">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->6</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="12">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->12</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c3 tile-96 border" data-prioritysort="2">
    <div class="tile-wrap show sewing clearfix">
        <div class="slug">
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-2 "></div>
            <div class="c3 tile-slug-3 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c12  proofing"></div>
        <div class="slot-cta">
             <h2><a href="TBD?icn=TBD&ici=96"
            title="25% Off Description."
            alt="25% Off Description.">
            <!-- 25% Off--></a></h2>

            <p>
                <!-- Description.-->2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a fast, concise solution, however, removing the "show" class does not hide these tiles. It instead leaves them in their original position and sorts all else around them.

Comment: I wasn't thinking. I must first hide all tiles with class "tile-wrap".  So problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: $("button").on("click", function () {
    $(".tile-wrap").parent().hide();
    elems.replaceWith(function (i, el) {
    return ret[i]
    })
    })

Comment: After testing this code I've discovered some issue. My slug icons disappear after the sort

Comment: @TomYoung Not certain which elements "slug icons" are ? If possible , can create stacksnippet / jsfiddle ? Thanks

Comment: The slug icons are added using jQuery.
    <div class="c3 tile-slug-1 onlineonly"></div>
    $('.onlineonly').append('<img height="42" width="54" src="../../../../masteritems/Slug4_061814.png" />');

Comment: I will try to get something into fiddle or stacksnippet soon.